# Is graph database suitable for accounting like software?

Tags: graph-databases

The problem:

We have a business process where we need to record many transactions between parties.
At the same time, the products&services that transactions are for can fall into many categories at the same time.

For example, we might have a transaction for iron rebar which falls into multiple categories at the same time, like: reinforcement, foundations, slabs...
Also, each transaction has a party that its made against.

The end goal is to get flexibility once we get to the reporting. We want to be able to make different reports counting same transactions within different contexts (categories).

At first, it sounds like graph db might be a good choice here since getting the report based on categories would be traversing the graph through particular vertices types.
On the other hand, not sure if I am missing something that might make life much more complicated compared to traditional rdbms?

Comment: Flexibility in reporting may be much easier to achieve with a RDBMS. It's easy to assign categories to transactions using a separate `CATEGORY` table which lists the categories for each transaction, and use that in `join` statements.

Comment: The aspect where graph DBs might be convenient here is that they make it straightforward to model complex ontologies and flexible relationships: Concept A is-subconcept-of Concept B and C, so all queries for B could also show transactions tagged with A. But in practice you might not have complicated ontologies, you might have an RDBMS with SQL extensions for recursive queries, and in all likelihood ACID is way more important than convenient queries.